# Effective resistance of a cut toroid

Tags: resistance

How do I find the resistance of a toroid or hollow cylinder that has been cut along a radius, that is, a straight cut from the center to the outer radius? The outer radius of the cylinder is *ro* and the inner radius is *ri*. The thickness is *w*. The resistivity is given is *p*. The general form of the resistance is *p l/w*, where *l* is the length. The cut is deemed very narrow.

Edit: The resistance is measured across the cylinder from the [exposed faces of the] cut portion.

[image]

Comment: From which point to which point ie where are your connections?

Comment: Thanks for replying; the question has been edited to answer your question. I hope it is sufficient.

Comment: Can you assume that ro-ri (=thickness of cylinder wall) is much smaller than (ro+ri)/2 (=mean radius of cylinder)? Then it becomes very simple...

Comment: Then the basic answer is the resistance is proportional to pi * D ie the circumerence which is the effective length less the width of the cut, as long as you assume no current through the gap.

Comment: The mean of the radius, ( (ro + ri) / 2 ), is 20x the thickness, w, of the cylinder.

Comment: The cut portion is assumed negligible, meaning 2*pi*r_effective.

Comment: So now you have all the info to put into the equation you gave : length, width and thickness...

Comment: i just do not know how to get the effective radius. I have tried plugging in the geometric mean and the arithmetic mean to no success.

Comment: In any case, we do not provide direct answers to homework questions. You must show what you've worked out so far and exactly what point you're stuck on; then we can guide you toward a solution.

Comment: It's not actually a homework problem. It's just a review question I've stumbled on. Anyway, I'm not providing the values for the question.

Comment: I have used the formula I stated in the question description. Resistance = Resistivity * Length / Area. Only the Length is dodgy. The Area is just the outer radius minus the inner radius and then multiplied by the thickness. The Resistivity is given.

Answer (score 1):

You shall cut into slices along the circumference.

Each slice will be \$\text{d}r\$ wide (from \$r\$ to \$r+\text{d}r\$), \$W\$ tall and \$2\pi r\$ long neglecting the radial cut.

Since all those slices will linearly drop the same voltage along the same angular distance we can assume there will be no radial currents as confirmed by this Femm4.2 simulation of a solid copper slotted toroid fed by 1V.

[image: Voltage plot]

*Above volatge plot shows no radial voltage gradient, i.e. no radial electric field nor current density.*

Hence all those slices will simply be parallel connected, just like in a kind of array of balanced Wheatstone bridges where "horizontal" branches carry no current at all.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBkpSB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Discrete elements schematics*

In this case it's much simpler summing individual conductivities instead of paralleling resistances.

Each slice would have resistance \$R=\rho\frac{l}{S}\$ and so \$G=\sigma\,\frac{S}{l}\$ in this case

$$ \text{d}G=\sigma\,\frac{W}{2\pi r}\,\text{d}r\quad\Rightarrow\quad G=\sigma\,\frac{W}{2\pi}\int_{r_i}^{r_o}\frac{\text{d}r}{r}=\sigma\,\frac{W}{2\pi}\,\ln\frac{r_o}{r_i}$$

Switching to resistance we get

$$ R=\rho\,\frac{2\pi}{W\ln\frac{r_o}{r_i}} $$

Interesting enough if \$r_o \approx r_i\$ the above tends to

$$R=\rho\,\frac{2\pi}{W\ln\frac{r_o}{r_i}}\rightarrow \rho\,\frac{2\pi\,\frac{r_o+r_i}{2}}{W(r_o-r_i)}=\rho\,\frac{l}{W\Delta r}$$

...tends to what first reckoned out using ring width and average length.

It may finally prove interesting to find out current density distribution.

Again each slice can be studied on its own so

$$ I=VG\quad \text{d}I=V\text{d}G=V\sigma\frac{W}{2\pi r}\text{d}r=V\sigma\frac{\text{d}S}{2\pi r}$$

being \$\text{d}S=W\text{d}r\$ the infinitesimal cross section of the slice

$$J=\frac{\text{d}I}{\text{d}S}=\frac{\sigma}{2\pi r}V $$

In short we have an hyperbolic current density distibution against the radius. This too is quite consistent: inner radius, shorter path, higher current.

[image]

*Current density plot and J(r) along red radius on top of toroid*

And again confirmed by the finite elements simulation.

Comment: Of course that assumption is incorrect. If you make your connection with a zero resistance plate at each end, the current will flow from the outside towards the center as you get away from the connections and crowd around the inner radius in a complex manner. This might be a reasonable estimate if the width of the ring is very small in comparison to the circumference.

Comment: Uhm I am sorry  but I cannot follow you. Let's  ground to 0V one of the two zero ohm plates and assume voltage V on the other one, and say the whole ring spreads over \$\alpha_{MAX}\$ angle. Now just take hypothesis of indipendent flow on each slice. Voltage along any one  will be \$V(\alpha)=V\,\alpha / \alpha_{MAX}\$. So for any slice same voltage for same angle, hence no radial current. I believe this confirms the starting hypothesis. I'd rather add the cut shall either be with surfaces along two radius (i.e. not parallel each other) or much shorter than circumference

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Please have a look to edits.

Comment: @carloc: Good work but intuition suggests that if we connect across the face of the cut we should see some higher current density vertically along the cut. It would be like a bunch of runners starting in a straight line and then bunching up and taking the racing line around the bend.

Comment: @Transistor Sometimes intuition is tricky ;) Just think of it as a kind of array of balanced Wheatstone bridge: no current in the "horizontal" branches.